# What is the default value of ClientBase<TChannel>.ClientCredentials?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out what default value `ClientBase<TChannel>.ClientCredentials` has when a new new class is created inheriting from `ClientBase`? E.g.:

```
public class A : ClientBase...
```

Does it use credentials of the logged in user if `ClientCredentials` not set explicitly? Can this behavior be different in different situations?

MSDN doesn't have any information regarding this.

Comment: Why not write a small piece of code that instantiates a `ClientBase<T>`, run it in the debugger, and inspect the `ClientCredentials` property?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a decompiler to look at the source code directly.

Comment: Or, check the source online: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs,430